# Spring not detecting application.properties

Tags: java, spring

Spring is not detecting my application.properties in the config folder.
The config file: (Sensitive Information hidden)

```
server.port = 8090
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:URL}:3306/DB
spring.datasource.username=USER
spring.datasource.password=PW
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
debug=true
```

Folder structure:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/62nsY.png]

Server.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Server.class);
        application.run();
    }
}
```

I tried putting the properties in he top and resources folder, nothing seems to work. If I try to load it via VM options it says resource not found. The config folder is marked as resource folder in IntelliJ

Comment: Hi Alex, interested to know the IDE you are using as I like the icons in the image you posted :)

Comment: It's IntelliJ with the Material Theme UI and Atom Material Icons

Comment: Refer this : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. The home directory for the run configuration needs to be set to the folder containing the resources folder. Which it wasn't before.
Folder Structure now:[image: Folder Structure]

Comment: You may not need 2 projects but rather 2 separate run configurations each with their own home eg /home/.../azchat/client and /home/.../azchat/server.

I suggest re-selecting your chosen answer because I can tell https://stackoverflow.com/a/74264123/4425643 probably didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I suggest you say "The home directory for the run configuration needs to be set to the folder containing the resources folder." or similar instead of it would be better to have two projects.

Comment: I did that now thanks

Answer (score 3):

application.properties file should be located in the resource directory.

Answer (score 1):

Spring has certain order for finding application.properties

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

SpringApplication will load properties from application.properties files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:

- A /config subdir of the current directory.
- The current directory
- A classpath /config package
- The classpath root

The list is ordered by precedence (locations higher in the list override lower items).